# How to add an 'order by' button when working with MVC structure on php?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, query-string

I'm pretty new to Laravel and the MVC structure.
I want to add two buttons to a page,  that will determine the order the products in it,  appear. (price -  low to high or high to low).
I'm trying to use the query string like so:

> ```
> href="{{ url('store/' . $cat_url . '?order=ASC') }}">Price: Low to High</a> | 
>
> href="{{ url('store/' . $cat_url . '?order=DESC') }}">Price: Hign to Low</a>
> ```

This is my product view :

```
  @foreach($products as $row)
    
    <div class="col-md-6">    
        <h3>{{$row['title']}}</h3>
        <p><img border="0" width="300" src="{{asset('images/' .$row['image'])}}"></p>
        <p>{!! $row['article'] !!}</p>
        <p><b>Price for pack:</b> {{ $row['price'] }}</p>
        <p>
            <input @if(Cart::get($row['id'])) disabled="disabled" @endif data-id="{{ $row['id']}}" type="button" value="Add to Order" class="add-to-order btn btn-success">
            <a href="{{ url('store/' . $cat_url . '/' . $row['url']) }}" class="btn btn-primary">More Details</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    @endforeach
```

This is the model:

```
static public function getProducts($category_url, &$data)
{    
    $data['products'] = [];
    
    if ($category = Category::where('url', $category_url)->first()) {
        $category = $category->toArray();
        $data['title'] = 'Candy | '. $category['title'];
        $data['cat_url'] = $category['url'];
        $data['cat_title'] = $category['title'];
        $products = Category::find($category['id'])->products;
        $data['products'] = $products->toArray();
    }
}
```

And his is the controller : (I'm trying to get the the 'order' key using 'Input::')

```
public function products($category_url)
{
    $order = Input::get('order');
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self::$data);
    return view('content.products', self::$data);
}
```

How can I add the query with the ORDER BY element to this model? How to get the value from the query string if the key appears?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static public function getProducts($category_url, &$data, $order = null){

    $data['products'] = [];

    if($category = Category::where('url', $category_url)->first()){
        ...
        if ($order) {
            $products = Category::find($category['id'])->products()->orderBy('price', $order)->get()
        } else {
            $products = Category::find($category['id'])->products;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it but  nothing happens.
Is it possible that this way $order is always null?

Comment: Any ideas?
I thougt since $ordedr gets his value in the controller before being sent to the model, maybe the model sets it as null always?
Thanks!

Comment: You have to pass the order when calling getProducts: $order = Input::get('order'); Product::getProducts($cat_url,$order, self::$data, $order);

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to use `MVC` structure but your passed the order in url like `query parameter` with `?` marks. This is not correct way in `MVC` you can use the `Routing` for that?

Give one try to this..

**Register your Routes likes this**

```
   Route::get('store/{cat_url}/{order?}', "ControllerName@products");
```

**Controller Method**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function products(Request request, $cat_url, $order="asc")
{
    Product::getProducts($cat_url,$order, self::$data);
    return view('content.products', self::$data);
}
```

**Model Method**

```
static public function getProducts($category_url, $order,&$data)
{    
    $data['products'] = [];

    if ($category = Category::where('url', $category_url)->orderBy("your_field_name",$order)->first()) {
        $category = $category->toArray();
        $data['title'] = 'Candy | '. $category['title'];
        $data['cat_url'] = $category['url'];
        $data['cat_title'] = $category['title'];
        $products = Category::find($category['id'])->products;
        $data['products'] = $products->toArray();
    }
}
```

**Your links**

```
href="{{ url('store/' . $cat_url . '/asc') }}">Price: Low to High</a> | 

href="{{ url('store/' . $cat_url . '/desc') }}">Price: Hign to Low</a>
```

Happy Coding...

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what is the 'request' part in the argument for products?

Comment: `Request` Is class provided by the `Laravel` to get `Information` of the current request made by user. It provides information like Method of the request (GET, POST..), Current Requested URL and Data posed by the user and much more.. For information you can read it's docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests

Comment: I think i would still rather use the ? in the query string :)
Do you think you an assist?
I'm still trying to wrap my head around Laravel and MVC so your solution is too hard for me...
Thank alot anyway..

Comment: Yes, You can able to use the `?` marks But `Laravel` Supports `MVC` and in `MVC` It is better to use the `Routing Parameter` to pass the data...

Comment: It's Solved your problem ?

Comment: My solution is  much easier than use the `?` marks because you have to get the data of it manually, but here `laravel` automatically pass that to your `controller's method`. Just go and changes in your `project` as per my `solution` you will get your problem solved. Even `I am started using laravel` from just `2 months ago`..

Comment: You can check my answer, I already added the `orderBy` that order your data in specific format. Are you try my code ?

Comment: I tried it but didn't know which request to use and kept getting 'missing arguement'

Comment: add this line of code to your controller file: `use Illuminate\Http\Request` at the top of controller..